# About fgetc() in C

Tags: c, string, file, fgetc

The code paragraph is as follow:

```
fp_t=fopen(temp_name,"r");
int j=0; 
do
{
    char ch=fgetc(fp_t);
    if(feof(fp_t)==0) all[i].note[j]=ch;
    j++;
} while(feof(fp_t)==0);
all[i].note[j-2]='\0';
fclose(fp_t);
```

The problem is about line `all[i].note[j-2]='\0';`. When running this code, the content in the file `fp_t` can be well-absorbed. But why it should be `j-2` when add `'\0'`?

I tried to change it as `j-1`, and if I print it to stdout, an `'\n'` is appended after the string. I confirmed that there is no `'\n'` in the original string.

Comment: The code is badly written and should not be used for learning (or for anything else).

Comment: This is not about C or `fgetc`, it’s about what the person who wrote the code wanted to do and what the input is. We don’t know either of those things.

Comment: It is because `j` was incorrectly incremented in the EOF case, so after the loop finishes its value is 1 too high. Poor quality code.

Comment: @Xiangnan Zhang, Review [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).  Code has nice infinite loop with `fp_t=fopen(temp_name,"w");`.

Comment: `all[i].note[j-2]='\0';` _assumes_ a prior character (perhaps `'\n'`) was read and needs to be zeroed.

Comment: An idiomatic loop could be `int ch; while((ch = fgetc(fp_t)) != EOF) { all[i].note[j++] = ch; } all[i].note[j] = '\0';` and also make a check on `j` bounds too.

Comment: The code assumes that the last character of the file is `\n`. It's overwriting that with the null terminator so the resulting string won't end with newline.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica He doesn't have `while (!feof(...)`. He has `do ... while (!feof(...)`, which is valid. However there is a mess in the middle of the loop.

Comment: @user207421 [(!feof(...), which is valid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78099049/about-fgetc-in-c?noredirect=1#comment137694884_78099049) --> consider `fgetc()` continually returns an `EOF` due to a persistent read _error_.  That makes for an infinite loop and certainly overfills the buffer.  `int ch; while ((ch = fgetc(...)) != EOF) { ... }` is better.  The linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359) expresses checking the `fgetc()` return value and not `feof()` for similar reasons. A sporadic read error, `all[i].note[j]=EOF;` is possible - and certainly not desirable.

Comment: @Xiangnan Zhang,  "if I print it to stdout, an '\n' is appended after the string. I confirmed that there is no '\n' in the original string." --> post the code that does that output.  Even better, post a [mcve].